# C# Efficient way calling a list of commands

Tags: c#, list, struct

I need to write a litte C# Winforms application to read many different values from a device over uart.
There should be a separate button for reading each value and writing it then to a dedicated label.
But there should be also ONE button to get all of theses readings done at once, one after each other.

Something like this:

```
button_1_click   ->  send command_1 (6 bytes) over uart  ->  receive value_1 ( uint8: 1 byte)  ->  write value_1 to label_1
button_2_click   ->  send command_2 (6 bytes) over uart  ->  receive value_2 ( uint16: 2 bytes)  ->  write value_2 to label_2
button_3_click   ->  send command_3 (8 bytes) over uart  ->  receive value_3 ( uint32: 4 bytes)  ->  write value_3 to label_3
...
...
button_20_click   ->  send command_20 (4 bytes) over uart  ->  receive value_20 ( uint8: 1 byte)  ->  write value_20 to label_20
...
button_read_ALL_click  ->  read ALL values one after each other and write them to dedicated labels
```

Is there an efficient way of doing this?

As I'm still a beginner with C#-programming (comming from microcontrollers c-code) and about to learn something,
I'd really appreciate some suggestions with explanations for better understanding.

Many thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient", exactly?

Comment: Your CPU will likely be much faster than the device you are reading data from. I would also assume the read-latency to be fixed, and that reads need to be done sequentially. So I would guess the issue would mostly be to deal with the latency, i.e. things like showing a progress bar if the reading all values takes a noticeable amount of time.

Comment: Efficient on (avoiding) wearing your fingers out could be something like `this.Controls.OfType<Button>().OrderBy(b => (b.Name.Length,b.Name)).ToList().ForEach(b => b.PerformClick())`

Comment: Look at [MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR)